# Finding profit/loss between a purchase and a sale.

Tags: probability

I am stuck with a problem:

A man buys a watch for Rs $1950$ in cash and sells it for $2200$ at an interest rate of interest $10\%$ *per annum* for one year. Find profit or loss.

My solution:

First I have calculated the one year interest on $2200$ Rs that is $220$ hence he will pay the total amount at the end $2420$ Rs. Again we calculate $1950$ for one year that is $195$ Rs the total amount $2145$ Rs. If we deduct the $2145$ from $2420$ it is $275$ Rs but my doubt is that it is not the correct answer.

I have got the another solution from a previous problem where he was earning $300$ Rs without interest, with interest he earns $275$ now actual earning is $25$ Rs. I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my reading of the problem, here's what is happening. He is selling the watch for $2200$ Rs at an interest rate of $10\%$ per year for one year. That means at the end of that year, someone else owes *him* $2420$ Rs for the watch. He originally paid $1950$ Rs *cash* for the watch, so we won't apply the interest rate to that--that's money he's already *lost*. Once he gets paid the $2420$ Rs, however, he will make that $1950$ Rs back, plus some extra. How much extra will he make back? That's the profit.